# How to fetch the row number of a Google Spread Sheet via Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google script I am using and I was wanting to insert the current row I am working with into a value which will be re added into a formula I set back in the spreadsheet. I want to do this in case someone resubmits the same data, so they are emailed the changes. At the moment this script is just a proof of concept for me, so I can then go on and code the entire process.

The problem I am having with the script is with the value currentRow. It seems to get the value of the first pass and then does not change it, which is problematic when you have more than one entry to process.

I use the value currentRow in the variable RESEND_EMAIL, so it can generate a formula which looks to see if the two columns are alike (I am going to use the date time stamp and copy it in just the first time to column D (also known as var resend[4]).

This way I can set the script to run automatically and check if this column is set as "Yes", in which case it will send and email again and then change the a value (shown here as email address - but I will use the timestamp instead) so that the formula RESEND_EMAIL changes resend back to "No".

How do I always ger the correct row Number in the value currentRow?

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 6)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
    var message = row[1];       // Second column
    var emailSent = row[2];     // Third column
    var resend = row[4];
    var extension = row [5];
    var currentRow = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
    var RESEND_EMAIL = "=IF(A"+ currentRow +"=D" + currentRow +",\"No\",\"Yes\")";


    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 3).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setFormula(RESEND_EMAIL);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
    if (resend == "Yes") {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
      message = message + " " + extension;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 4).setValue(emailAddress);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }     

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in your code `i` variable value becomes the current row.

```
...
var currentRow = startRow + i;
...
```

Comment: This isn't a comment about your answer, it's about improving questions. You've been answering lots of GAS questions! When you do, if you see that the question needs improving, including retagging, please take a minute or two to edit it. Bonus: When this question gets properly tagged with [google-apps-script], you'll get recognition for it in the [top users list](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/topusers)! (I've retagged several hundred questions in the past few months, and could use some help!)